# Why isn't "this" known at compile time in a consteval constructor?

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm writing a class to wrap around part of a C-based library that works with devices, where each device is configured with a callback function poiner for handling data. An instance of `MyClass` would be made for each device. See below:

```
struct DeviceConfig {
    void (*callback)(char *data);
};

class MyClass {
private:
    DeviceConfig config;

public:
    void myCallback(char *data);

    MyClass() {
        // Would like to set config.callback so that a call to it will result in a call of this->myCallback(data).
    }
};
```

Since a capturing lambda can't be converted to a function pointer, I've tried the following as a workaround:

```
template<MyClass *MC>
auto binder() {
    return [](char *data) { MC->myCallback(data); };
}

MyClass::MyClass() {
    config.callback = binder<this>();
}
```

However, the compiler (GCC latest) doesn't like `binder` being used in the constructor, as `this` isn't necessarily known at compile-time, though I know that instances of `MyClass` will only be declared at compile-time.

C++20 introduced `consteval` functions (and constructors) which ["must produce a compile-time constant."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval).  However, adding `consteval` to the constructor and/or `binder` doesn't affect the compiler's output. `constexpr` doesn't change things either.

If an object can be initialized at compile-time, why can't the object's `this` be known at compile-time too? Can the above be achieved through some other manner?

Comment: `this` is effectively a parameter to member functions.

Comment: @NicolBolas That does seem to be the correct duplicate, but I think you should add an answer there explaining why it isn't allowed even for `consteval` functions.

Comment: @NicolBolas This is the reference I have, but you may have a different one: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-proposals/FvE9w5_onQo/Nbm26D2uBwAJ

Comment: Instantiating templates during constant evaluation gets messy.

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't understand how that question answers mine, it doesn't deal with classes or objects at all. It certainly doesn't answer why `this` is unavailable in a consteval constructor.

Comment: @NicolBolas Is it helpful to know that to `static MyClass mc; mc.config.callback = binder<&mc>()` works? The issue is the assignment within a constructor.

Comment: @clyne: Classes and objects are irrelevant here; what matters is that you're executing a function. And `this` is a parameter to member functions, including constructors. That's why it's not a constant expression.

Comment: Found the question I was thinking of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57226797/will-consteval-allow-using-static-assert-on-function-arguments. And the referenced mental model paper: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0992r0.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Constructors are functions, just like any other. They have very few special privileges compared to other functions, and the constant expression behavior of their parameters is not one of them.

`this` is essentially a parameter to all non-static member functions. Parameters are [*never*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27591970/734069) constant [expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57226813/734069). Therefore, `this` can not be used in a context that requires a constant expression. It does not matter how you create a class instance. It does not matter how you call it. Parameters to `constexpr/consteval` functions are never constant expressions, and that includes `this`.

Comment: I understand. However, I would argue that the functionality I'm seeking should be possible in a `constexpr/consteval` context. I've put together an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/JdVnK3) on Compiler Explorer; it appears the compiler can know what it needs to for achieving what I'm looking for, the functionality just isn't there.

Comment: @clyne: What "should be possible" is irrelevant; the language *does not allow it* at the present time. There are proposals for allowing constexpr parameters (presumably including `this`), but those are in the C++23 (at best) timeframe and thus do not represent C++20.

Comment: I wanted to know why this functionality isn't possible; proposals for making this possible are significant, and it would have been nice to see them included in your answer. Saying this is not possible and leaving it at that reads a lot like "this would never be possible," which appears to not be the case.

Comment: @clyne: But that's not the question you asked. You asked why the code you wrote doesn't work. And it doesn't work because parameters are not constant expressions in C++. Asking if it is possible to ever modify C++ to make parameters able to be constant expressions is a completely different question. And rather out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @NicolBolas: While asking for predictions about decisions that haven’t been made is not appropriate, asking about what technical barriers there might be to extending the language is not, and can be educational.  As a relevant example, considering that even a `consteval` function must have *one* return type is very helpful in understanding the lack of constant-expression status for its parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer does explain why `this` can't be used within the constructor; however, I also asked if there was a workaround to achieve what I wanted. I've found a workaround, and shared that work in another StackOverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62199060/can-i-initialize-an-objects-c-style-function-pointer-at-compile-time-so-that-it).

To save a click, here's the last iteration of my code:

```
struct DeviceConfig {
    void (*callback)(const char *);
};

template<auto& v, auto f>
constexpr auto member_callback = [](auto... args) { (v.*f)(args...); };

class MyClass {
private:
    DeviceConfig config;

public:
    consteval MyClass(const DeviceConfig& cfg = {}) :
        config(cfg) {}

    template<MyClass& MC>
    constexpr static MyClass& init() {
        MC.config.callback = member_callback<MC, &MyClass::myCallback>;
        return MC;
    }

    void myCallback(const char *data);
};

int main()
{
    constinit static MyClass mc = (mc = MyClass(), MyClass::init<mc>());
}
```