# Can I initialize an object's C style function pointer at compile time so that it calls the object's member function?

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm writing a class to wrap around a library that requires callback function pointers. See below:

```
struct LibraryConfig {
    // Omitting other members...
    void (*callback)(const char *);
};

class MyClass {
private:
    LibraryConfig m_config;

public:
    MyClass(const LibraryConfig &config) {
        // Initialize m_config using config, would like to set callback so that it calls
        // this->myCallback().
    }

    void myCallback(const char *);
};
```

Only static instances of MyClass will be declared, so construction can be kept within compile-time. I've tried lambdas and template functions that take MyClass pointers, but I either can't accomplish this within the constructor, or can't achieve this at compile-time (getting the address of an instance through `this` or `&myClass` at compile-time doesn't seem possible).

`constexpr` parameters may be allowed in the future, making this trivial to implement, but is there a way to accomplish this right now with C++20?

Comment: fwiw, constexpr parameters are unlikely to ever be added to the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is apparently possible. See the below snippet:

```
struct LibraryConfig {
    void (*callback)(const char *);
};

class MyClass {
private:
    LibraryConfig config;

public:
    consteval MyClass(const LibraryConfig& cfg) :
        config(cfg) {}

    void myCallback(const char *data);
};

int main()
{
    constinit static MyClass mc = {{
        [](const char *data) { mc.myCallback(data); }
    }};
}
```

See a working example on Compiler Explorer [here](https://godbolt.org/z/sT1OTk). Since `mc` is static, the lambda is allowed to access it without capture. There may be room for improvement on this solution, e.g. having the lambda be produced by a function.

**Edit:**

I've come up with a generalized function to create the lambda:

```
template<auto& inst, auto func>
consteval auto make_member_callback()
{
    return []<typename... Args>(Args... args) { (inst.*func)(args...); };
}
```

This allows the following to be possible ([compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/gj3qgA)):

```
constinit static MyClass mc {{
    make_member_callback<mc, &MyClass::myCallback>()
}};
```

**Edit 2:**

Here is my final try at this, where the initialization is done within the class:

```
struct LibraryConfig {
    void (*callback)(const char *);
};

template<auto& v, auto f>
constexpr auto member_callback = [](auto... args) { (v.*f)(args...); };

class MyClass {
private:
    LibraryConfig config;

public:
    consteval MyClass(const LibraryConfig& cfg = {}) :
        config(cfg) {}

    template<MyClass& MC>
    constexpr static MyClass& init() {
        MC.config.callback = member_callback<MC, &MyClass::myCallback>;
        return MC;
    }

    void myCallback(const char *data);
};

int main()
{
    constinit static MyClass mc = (mc = MyClass(), MyClass::init<mc>());
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is UB, since you are using `mc` in its own initializer.

Comment: `DeviceConfig` vs `LibraryConfig` is this a typo?

Comment: @idclev463035818 It was, fixed. Thanks

Comment: Now your demo uses `DeviceConfig` though.

Comment: @dfri / cigien sure? `mc` is in the lambdas body and will only be used after the object is fully alive

Comment: @cigien Sorry. In the future I'll try to make everything consistent, but right now the functionality is what I'm trying to show.

Comment: `mc` has static storage duration and therefore is not captured at all. Only automatic storage duration and `this` are capturable. Static storage duration are basically global variables and cannot be captured.